# Where is state held in PyMC model?

Tags: python, pymc, mcmc

Given the following model, my question is how does `S` know anything about `alpha`, `beta`, and `theta`? I've seen examples where `MCMC` is given a model specified in a separate file (i.e. as a Python module), and that makes some sense to me. But here I have not passed any data into `S` explicitly. Just trying to understand how this works.

```
import pymc as pm
import numpy as np

n = 5 * np.ones(4, dtype=int)
x = np.array([-0.86, -0.3, -0.05, 0.73])

alpha = pm.Normal('alpha', mu=0, tau=0.01)
beta = pm.Normal('beta', mu=0, tau=0.01)

@pm.deterministic
def theta(a=alpha, b=beta):
    """theta = logit^{-1}(a+b)"""
    return pm.invlogit(a + b * x)

d = pm.Binomial('d',n=n,p=theta,value=np.array([0.,1.,3.,5.]),observed=True)

S = pm.MCMC(db='pickle')
S.sample(iter=10000, burn=5000, thin=2)
pm.Matplot.plot(S)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the `input` parameter for a `pymc.Model` or derived class is `None`, it sucks all the variables out of `__main__`.  [See here for the gory details](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/blob/de77eecaa6c0e6089770832bae28a7c720251cc3/pymc/Model.py#L91-L97).  It appears that we are not supposed to use this magic anymore... when I run your code I get the following:

```
/homes/abie/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc/Model.py:93: UserWarning: The MCMC() syntax is deprecated. Please pass in nodes explicitly via M = MCMC(input).
  'The MCMC() syntax is deprecated. Please pass in nodes explicitly via M = MCMC(input).')
```

Comment: Ah, fair enough. I think I got that example straight from the docs. lol

Comment: You should make an issue in their GitHub, I bet the devs would update the docs if they knew about it.